# How about a new hat for Joining / Opting for Winter Bash?

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash-2015

I'm a big, big fan of Hats, especially when it's with Winter Bash.

I have a small query  [*or, consider suggestion*] related to the Hats Collection available.

All I want to ask, Can't there be a dedicated hat for ***opting to join*** the Winter Bash. Something called *`"I've joined the party"`* or similar?

I know it is not possible in WB 2014 but if you all share the same view, can we have it in WB 2015?

It's all about hats, you know. :-)

Cheers to winter bash 2014 and all the best for the same in 2015.

<sup>P.S - Just for clarification, this question/ suggestion is because, I want to start wearing a hat *as soon as* I join the bash. Personally, I'm too impatient to wait till I *earn* my first [read, second, as per the proposal]  one.</sup>

Comment: What about sites that enable hats by default? Do you have to opt out then opt in again, or do you automatically get the hat without having to do anything?

Comment: @Antony Thank you for the edit. I would like to say, if the hats are _enabled_ by default, then this proposed hat can also be _awarded_ by default. :-)

Comment: This year, you got the Santa Lucia hat if you used the site at all on the 15th. I was counting that as the "give-me" hat, personally.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but not good.

First off, there is a solution to Antony's comment:

> What about sites that enable hats by default? Do you have to opt out then opt in again, or do you automatically get the hat without having to do anything?

Solution: Make optting in WB not default, but manually. You'll have to click <kbd>I opt in</kbd> on a specific site that you want to join. (Just like the button <kbd>I love hats</kbd> on SO. The WB [FAQ](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/faq) has that.)

Second, Hatz are made just for fun. See [this question.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246131/why-collecting-winter-bash-hats) In my opinion, clicking <kbd>I opt in</kbd> or <kbd>I love hats</kbd> and earning a new hat is not fun at all.

Third, base on the above solution, if people forget to opt in, then they won't be getting hats. And result? There'll be a whole "OMG MAH HATZ R GONE" questions on MSE.

This is purely my opinion.

Comment: Thank you sharing your view, I respect that. However, IMHO, I am personally _too_ impatient to wait till the time I collect my first hat. I want to start wearing a hat _as soon as_ I opt for WB 2015. That's fun for me. :-)

Comment: and also `if people forget to opt in,`...this doesn't seem valid. Isn't it the case now itself?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Immediately earn your first hat, Chameleon, by changing your profile picture.

Comment: @SouravGhosh By default you are opted in automatically on all sites on SE except SO. You have to click "I hate hats" to opt out.

Comment: Well, you know, that's a _secret hat_ and _maybe_ will take time to guess the activity based on which that will be awarded.

Comment: @SouravGhosh True, true. How about "Using the app"?

Comment: Well, in that case, this hat should be given automatically. You opt out and woosh..hats are gone. After all, you're clicking the `opt out` button knowing the effects, right?

Comment: What about `How about "Using the app"`? Sorry I did not get your point. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm kind of in a hurry right now. I may have to elaborate later.

Comment: There's a hat which objective is to post using the SE app. You can instantly earn that hat in WB.

Comment: I absolutely agree, but then , there's a small `if` somewhere around. Entirely from my personal experience, I know people _still_ without smartphones but enthusiast enough to be a part of the community. :-)

Comment: Hmmm... This is true. But is the hat fun? When you earn a hat just by joining WB like the badge Autobiographer?

Comment: Well, for me, _The more the merrier_. Also, I'm a bit impatient to wear the hat ASAP...you know. :-)

Comment: I see. The original purpose of Hatz are for fun. Maybe you're misunderstanding the whole idea ;)

Comment: Well, maybe, maybe not. for me, `one more hat` is equal to `a level up in fun`. YMMV. Nevertheless, thanks for sharing your view. Appreciate that.